# Parse Apache Formatted URLs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, apache, url

How can I take in a Apache Common Log file and list all of the URLs in it in a neat histogram like:

```
/favicon.ico                      ##
/manual/mod/mod_autoindex.html        #
/ruby/faq/Windows/                    ##
/ruby/faq/Windows/index.html    #
/ruby/faq/Windows/RubyonRails   #
/ruby/rubymain.html                   #
/robots.txt                           ########
```

Sample of test file:

```
65.54.188.137 - - [03/Sep/2006:03:50:20 -0400] "GET /~longa/geomed/ppa/doc/localg/localg.htm HTTP/1.0" 200 24834
65.54.188.137 - - [03/Sep/2006:03:50:32 -0400] "GET /~longa/geomed/modules/sv/scen1.html HTTP/1.0" 200 1919
65.54.188.137 - - [03/Sep/2006:03:53:51 -0400] "GET /~longa/xlispstat/code/statistics/introstat/axis/code/axisDens.lsp HTTP/1.0" 200 15962
65.54.188.137 - - [03/Sep/2006:04:03:03 -0400] "GET /~longa/geomed/modules/cluster/lab/nm.pop HTTP/1.0" 200 66302
65.54.188.137 - - [03/Sep/2006:04:11:15 -0400] "GET /~longa/geomed/data/france/names.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 20706
74.129.13.176 - - [03/Sep/2006:04:14:35 -0400] "GET /~jbyoder/ambiguouslyyours/ambig.rss HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

This is what I have right now (but I'm not sure how to make the histogram):

```
...
---

$apache_line = /\A(?<ip_address>\S+) \S+ \S+ \[(?<time>[^\]]+)\] "(?<method>GET|POST) (?<url>\S+) \S+?" (?<status>\d+) (?<bytes>\S+)/
$parts = apache_line.match(file)
$p parts[:ip_address], parts[:status], parts[:method], parts[:url]

def get_url(file)
    hits = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=0}
    File.read(file).to_a.each do |line|
    while $p parts[:url]
        if k = k
            h[k]+=1
            puts "%-15s %s" % [k,'#'*h[k]]
        end
    end
end

...
---
```

Here is the full question: http://pastebin.com/GRPS6cTZ Pseudo code is fine.

Comment: Now now, just because you deleted your post showing that it was a homework question doesn't mean that you can get around that by claiming it is not.

Comment: Phrogz, I never claimed this wasn't homework. Can you please add histogram to my tags as I cannot?

Comment: @에이바 Since you asked the question with the `homework` tag, then deleted it and asked a smaller version without that tag, I rudely assumed that you were trying to hide this fact. I apologize. See my answer for help on creating the histogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create a hash mapping each path to the number of hits. For convenience, I suggest using a Hash that sets the value to 0 when you ask for a path it hasn't seen before. For example:

   ```
   hits = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k]=0 }
   ...
   hits["/favicon.ico"] += 1
   hits["/ruby/faq/Windows/"] += 1
   hits["/favicon.ico"] += 1
   p hits
   #=> {"/favicon.ico"=>2, "/ruby/faq/Windows/"=>1}
   ```
2. In case the log file is really huge, instead of slurping the whole thing into memory, process the lines one at a time. (Look through the methods of the [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) class.)
3. Because Apache log file formats don't have standard delimiters, I'd suggesting using a regular expression to take each line and separate it into the chunks you want. Assuming you're using Ruby 1.9, I'm going to use named captures for clean access to the methods later on. For example:

   ```
   apache_line = /\A(?<ip_address>\S+) \S+ \S+ \[(?<time>[^\]]+)\] "(?<method>GET|POST) (?<url>\S+) \S+?" (?<status>\d+) (?<bytes>\S+)/
   ...
   parts = apache_line.match(log_line)
   p parts[:ip_address], parts[:status], parts[:method], parts[:url]
   ```
4. You might want to choose to filter these based on the status code. For example, do you want to include in your graph all the 404 hits where someone mistyped? If you're not slurping all the lines into memory, you won't be using `Array#select` but instead skipping over them during your loop.
5. After you have gathered all your hits, then its time to write out the results. Some helpful tips:

   1. `Hash#keys` can give you all the keys of the array (the paths) at once. You probably want to write out all the paths with the same amount of whitespace, so you need to figure out which is the longest. Perhaps you want to `map` the paths to their lengths and then get the `max` element, or perhaps you want to use [`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001507) to find the longest path and then find its length.
   2. Although geeky, using `sprintf` or `String#%` is a great way to lay out formatted reports. For example:

      ```
      puts "%-15s %s" % ["Hello","####"]
      #=> "Hello           ####"
      ```
   3. Just like you needed to find the longest name for good formatting, might want to to find the URL with the most hits, so that you can scale your longest amount of hashes to that value. `Hash#values` will give you an array of all values. Alternatively, perhaps you have a requirement that one `#` must always represent 100 hits, or something.
   4. Note that `String#*` lets you create a string by repetition:

      ```
      p '#'*10
      #=> "##########"
      ```

If you have specific questions with your code, ask more questions!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I won't give you the exact answer, but Simone Carletti has implemented a [Ruby class](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/02/apache-log-regex-a-lightweight-ruby-apache-log-parser/) to parse Apache log files. You might start there and look at how he does things.

Comment: This isn't really my problem it's more of how to make the histogram.